# Splitting office document with large number of pages into multiple files

Tags: linux, docker, ms-office, amazon-sqs, libreoffice

We use libreoffice in headless mode inside docker to convert Office documents (.docx, .pptx etc) into PDF before going into the next step in the pipeline. We found that depending on the size and complexity of the document specially when we have a number of pages (~100), the memory consumption goes so high that the instance crashes. Is there any tool that we can use to split Office documents into multiple chunks so that libreoffice only has to deal with files with small footprint?

Of course the tool has to be able to run in headless mode inside docker.

Thanks

Comment: After you convert to pdf, you can split the pdf into individual pages with `pdftk burst name.pdf`  By default spit pages are named `pg_0001.pdf, pg_0002.pdf ...` (e.g. `printf ("pg_%04d.pdf", pgnum);` That would allow you to create the original pdf. split it into pages, unload the original from memory and then just work with the needed pages.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for looking into this. Our problem is libreoffice itself cannot hold the document in-memory (before it converts to PDF). File types we have issues are .docx, .pptx, .xlsx etc.

Comment: My thought is this then. You need to look at the contents of the original .docx files. I suspect they contain large non-text objects (e.g. images, etc.) that are ballooning the size of the conversion. Images added that may be 1600x900 in size that are scaled to 400x300 in the document, but the image content remains full-size. Optimizing the .docx content can reduce the .docx size by a factor of 10 or more. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to convert a "library-of-Congress" amount of text without running into memory limitation.